# EXEC NODE script from PHP (stop on async task)

Tags: php, node.js, console

I try to run my script:

```
$exec_string = '/usr/bin/node /www/laravel/sitemap';
exec($exec_string,$output);
```

My script work fine from terminal (chmod and chown == ok). But when I run it from exec it finished after first async task. Node:

```
function callAddLink()
{
     1..100 async_function() {

          code and code...

          IT STOPS HERE. NEXT ASYNC TASK NEVER CALLS!
     }
}
```

Why it can happen? Code works fine everywhere except php exec.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an ampersand to the end of your command, will redirect the output stream until the program exits.

```
$exec_string = '/usr/bin/node /www/laravel/sitemap &';
exec($exec_string,$output);
```

The default behaviour for PHP exec function is to be synchronise/blocking (to wait until the program has exited before moving on). But when executing an asynchronous node CLI application it seems to return before the application has exited.